# how can i fix this : i can see through faces with no x ray or other see through settings enabled

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, faces, visibility

I don't know what happened but whenever I'm outside of orthographic mode faces start to go crazy seeing through the mesh with no x-ray, no wireframe or no limit selection turned on.

It's both in edit and object mode. It looks like a shading problem. I don't know if it's something I did wrong or a bug.

I tried to see if it was overlapping but it isn't.
This is the second time I have had this problem.

In Blender 2.79:
[image]

Comment: That does look like all the right settings, so time for some more unorthodox suggestions. The Mesh looks quite big, have you applied Scaling. Can you try shrinking it? I have worked with some huge Meshes in Blender and never seen this issue. Create a new .blend and try importing the Object to see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Also, try adjusting the clipping range to the model.